# Dropdown toggle not working properly for Firefox-Android

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, cross-browser, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a dropdown that I trigger manually in order to have it closed when any click is performed outside of it (and it is open).

And this code works in every browser but for Firefox for Android.  Why is that?
It is like the event parameter is not reaching the function ok.

```
     var dropdownClicked = function(event){
        $('.dropdown').toggleClass('open');  //IT WORKS FOR ALL OF THEM
        //$(this).toggleClass('open');       //IT WORKS FINE IN EVERY BROWSER BUT FIREFOX-ANDROID
        //$(this)[0].toggleClass('open');    //IT WORKS JUST FOR FIREFOX-ANDROID
        event.stopPropagation();
    };

    $('.dropdown').click( function(event){ dropdownClicked(event) });
```

And then I have this version that works for all of them:

```
    $('.dropdown').click(function(event){
        $(this).toggleClass('open'); //Works for all of them
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
```

In case that you need the html. Here it is:

```
       <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Select projects <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="download">
                    <li>
                        <a id="show-game" class="show-tag">Game Development</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a id="show-web" class="show-tag">Web Development</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: Try creating a jsFiddle reproducing your issue. Also, what version of Bootstrap are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Shot in the dark: FF is getting tripped up on "this". Try passing "$(this)" as a parameter to your dropdownClicked function and call it it "X" for instance. Then try: X.toggleClass('open');

```
var dropdownClicked = function(event, X){
    X.toggleClass('open');
};

$('.dropdown').click( function(event){ dropdownClicked(event, $(this)) });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8d25m/